# Make one column of an HTML table from array a clickable URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

I am generating an HTML data table using Google App Script and am trying to get the URL result to be clickable.

Where should I be adding this?
Should it be another function?

```
 function createTable(dataArray) {
    if(dataArray){
      var result = "<table class='table table-sm' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                   "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                     "<tr>"+                               
"<th scope='col'>Name</th>"+
"<th scope='col'>URL</th>"+
"<th scope='col'>Type</th>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                  "</thead>";
      for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          //result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteBtn' onclick='deleteData(this);'>Delete</button></td>";
          result += "<td></td>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs editBtn' onclick='editData(this);'>Edit</button></td>";
          for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
              result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
          }
          result += "</tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      var div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
      div.innerHTML = result;
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
      var div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
      div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [tag A](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) to your element to make it href tag that able to click (add `target="_blank"` to make URL open in new tab)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I add this to the code, it makes the whole row a link:        
       result += "<td><a href='https://www.google.com'>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</a></td>";  How can I make it so that a) only the URL value is made into a link and b) pass each row's different URL to where the static example is now?

Comment: tag 'tr' is for each row, tad 'td' is for each column in 'tr' row
So. if you want to click row to redirect to another URL, you need to set onclick to <tr> tag it will be the whole row in table, but if you set into <td> tag it will be only for that column.

<td> <a href=""/> </td> is mean assign tag <a> in to tag <td>

I suggest you read about:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp